# h tag changes using css in opencart

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

Im trying to implement a more accurate h tag structure on my opencart site for seo purposes. For those that are unfamiliar with the html in opencart, most pages are split with php calls being made to seperate header, main body and footer files. I want to have a h1 tag that is slightly different on the main page to the product page by writing internal css to change the font size to something slightly smaller.

I therefore added the code (below) to the top of the products page which seems to work but leaves a massive white space at the bottom of the page below the footer. Example at this link: http://www.imbued.co.uk/sleep/aborro-bed

How do i implement this using css correctly?

```
<style>
h1 {
font-size:2em !important;
margin:0 0 20px !important
}
</style>
```

Comment: You may have to use a negative number for your top margin. Have you tried `margin-top` with different values?

Comment: Say for example using `margin-top:-10px;` which won't override your existing `margin` values, except the top one, being `0`.

Comment: **Q:** Why do you have your `<style>...` on top of `<!DOCTYPE html>`? Testing purposes? If not for testing, then you'd be best to put that inside your `<head></head>` tags.

Comment: Well yes I was just trying it out eventhough I know it isn't the correct way of doing it but google chrome seems to read it ok minus this massive white space the bottom. I know it should go within the head section but then that would mean all h1 tags would be the same if i put it within header.php

Comment: @Fred Im assuming the answer below is how I should split the h1 tag into different classes?

Comment: @green4rrow I would say to try `Arbaoui Mehdi's` answer below, sure. However, have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: @green4rrow Another thing I just thought of would be to use the `active` selector. Something to the affect of `h1:active {set your values}` might work, then set your values for it when in different sections, that way all `h1` tags in the current page will have that same value.

Comment: @Fred My apologies, I didn't quite follow your response at first and have already tried the answer below which works as required too. I've also just read that using classes doesn't get you penalised in terms of SEO

Comment: @green4rrow Funny you should say that, I was just about to say "Or even an `h1.classname`" lol Well, I'm just glad you found a solution, cheers.

Comment: @Fred Hah! Now to clean up the rest of the mess I made when I started this website with 0 experience

Comment: @green4rrow I started with `0` experience also (self-taught), we all did. **That's what we call in the biz "experience".** ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**"h1" on main page:**

```
#content-home h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: red;
}
```

**"h1" on product page:**

```
.product-info h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: green;
}
```